# Php checked checkbox from loop

Tags: php, database

I have information from the database that i list using foreach loop:

```
<table class="price_table">
   <caption>Prices</caption>
   <?php if($price= getCarPricePeriod($car->ID)):?>
        <?php foreach ($prices as $price): ?>
             <tr>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="price" value="<?= $price['Price'];?>"> </td>
                 <td><?= $price['Price'];?>$</td>
             </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
</table>
```

So with this loop i get prices with radio button. How to make first item from loop be `checked`. Just first need to be checked

If i add `checked` in loop all items will be checked or randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a variable flagging your element is first:

```
<table class="price_table">
    <caption>Prices</caption>
    <?php if($price= getCarPricePeriod($car->ID)):
        $first = true;
        foreach ($prices as $price): ?>
             <tr>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="price" value="<?= $price['Price'];?> <?= $first ? 'checked' : '' ?>"> </td>
                 <td><?= $price['Price'];?>$</td>
             </tr>
        <?php $first = false;
        endforeach; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to do it is to have a variable to be the identifier

```
<table class="price_table">
   <caption>Prices</caption>
   <?php  if($price= getCarPricePeriod($car->ID)):?>
        <?php $checked=true; foreach ($prices as $price): ?>
             <tr>
                 <td><input type="radio" name="price" value="<?= $price['Price'];?>"<?=$checked ? ' checked' : '';?>> </td>
                 <td><?= $price['Price'];?>$</td>
             </tr>
        <? $checked = false; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
</table>
```